# Learning HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm just learning myself how to use hashMaps, can someone check this piece of code I have written and tell me if it's correct? The idea is to have a list of staff working in a company, I want to add and remove staff from a hashMap.

```
public class Staff
{
    private HashMap<String, String>id;

    public Staff(String name, String number)
    {
        id = new HashMap<>(name,number);
    }

    public addStaff()
    {
       id.add("Joe","1234A2);   
    }

    public removeStaff()
    {
       id.remove("Joe","1234A2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class, you need to change / add things to look like:

```
private HashMap<String, String> id;

public Staff(String name, String number)
{
    id = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public addStaff()
{
   id.put("Joe","1234A2");   
}

public removeStaff()
{
   id.remove("Joe");
}
```

to use a `HashMap` properly.

Note that `addStaff(`) and `removeStaff()` are not likely to be very useful for most purposes because they only add and remove the one staff member "Joe". A more useful way of doing things would be

```
public void addStaff(StaffMember member) {
   id.put(member.getName(), member);
}

public StaffMember get(String name) {
   // this will return null if the member's name isn't a key in the map.
   return id.get(name);
}
```

What makes a `Map` different from other data structures is that it has a "key" which allows you to possibly retrieve one item. You cannot use a `Map` in the ways that give you a boost in performance if you don't have the item's key beforehand.

Note that `HashMap`s require keys to follow the rules for equality correctly in addition to equal items returning the same hashCode.  Basically if on object `a` and another object `b` are considered equal, then

```
// Reflexive property
a.equals(a) must return true

// Symmetric property
if (a.equals(b)) then b.equals(a) must return true

// Transitive property
if (a.equals(b) and b.equals(c)) then a.equals(c) must return true

// Additional requirements to make hash related algorithms work properly
a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() // must be true
```

The `hashCode()` part is above and beyond simple equality, and is required for the `HashMap` to work correctly.

Comment: HashMap.get() does not remove the object from the map.

Comment: @Mikaveli, sorry it was a cut and paste from the original code above.  Didn't notice that the strings were unterminated as the method names on the map being wrong led to tunnel vision.

Comment: `id.remove("Joe");` only.  This method only takes 1 argument.

Comment: @toto, already did that five minutes ago, refresh your screen.

Comment: `Note that HashMaps require elements to follow the rules for equality and key equality correctly.` is incorrect. Only the **keys** need equality properly defined, the values don't. Unless by "elements" you mean keys.

Comment: The rules for equality include the `reflexive property` the `symmetric property` and the `transitive property`  but I can easily see how my addition of `key equality` confused the issue.  I'll edit it again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me, however I would have created a Employee class and use a unique id for each staff member.

```
class Employee {
  Integer id;
  String name;
}

Map<Integer, Employee> staff = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
```

This way you can extend the staff info at will without redefining your staff map. Also never assume that human names are unique.

Comment: Yeah sorry shoulda went with the staff number as the key and the name as the value

Answer (score 1):

First of all please read this 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html
and a lot of things will be more clear for you.
Then take a look here for some samples:

- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=369
- http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/courses/Languages/JavaExamples/jgl3.1.0/doc/api/com.objectspace.jgl.examples.HashMapExamples.html

Comment: [read this], read what? [look here], look at what? Provide a link when pointing to something.